# Finding range for integral from inequilty

Tags: probability, integration, inequality

I have a function which is constant:
$$ 
  f_{XY}(x, y) = \left.
  \begin{cases}
    1/2, & \text{if } |x| + |y| \leq 1 \\
    0, & \text{else }
  \end{cases}
  \right\} 
$$

I want to find the marginal probability density function for x which is defined as
$$ f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY} (x, y) dy $$
So I just need to find the correct range for this integral:
$$
\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy 
$$
I'm having issues finding the right range for the integral. My teacher showed us something with expanding the inequality:

$$ |x| + |y| \leq 1 $$
$$\implies  |y| \leq 1 - |x|$$
next step is wrong, but i recall the structure looked something like this
$$\implies  |x| + 1 \leq y \leq 1 - |x|$$

and then use that for the integral:
$$
\frac12\int_{|x| + 1 }^{1 - |x|} dy 
$$
Any suggestions for how to find these? I know the answer is 2, but I would love to know how to expand the inequality

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220049/integral-boundaries-of-random-variable-when-xy-leq-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_X(x)=\int_{-(1-|x|)}^{1-|x|} \frac  1 2 dy=1-|x|$ for $|x| \leq 1$.

$|y| \leq r$ means $-r \leq y \leq r$. Take $r=1-|x|$.

Comment: Simple and crystal clear explanation - thanks for helping me.